# Datatype factory in jre 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-6

DataTypeFactory class is inside the rt.jar inside the jre lib. calling newDuration and passing in a long. here is the relevant code.

```
DatatypeFactory factoryImpl = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
setValue(factoryImpl.newDuration(tempBigDecimal.longValue()))
```

our application on the old servers(jre 6) sets value = PT10H0M0.000S
after moving application to the new servers (jre 8) it
sets value = P0Y0M0DT10H0M0.000S

is there a jdk setting that can set the value to only return the H/M/S and exclude Y/M/D like we do in jdk 6 ?

Comment: What are the values of `newDuration.getClass().getCanonicalName()`, `System.getProperty("java.version")` and `System.getProperty("java.vendor")` on both the "old" and the "new" server(s)?

Comment: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl/
1.8.0_25/
Oracle Corporation

Comment: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl/ 1.6.0_35/ Oracle Corporation

Comment: I don't have a saved setup for 6u35, but **assuming setValue does toString** in both 6u31 and 6u45 as well as 8 I get `P0Y0M0DT10H0M0.000S` and I see no hint in the JDK src.zip of anything that would alter this. Can you verify `newDuration(...).toString()`? Where does `setValue(?)` come from and could it resolve as or do something JDK-dependent?

Comment: I compared the Java 6 and Java 8 versions of `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl` and `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DurationImpl` and there’s not the slightest difference in the relevant areas. They always produce duration instances with all non-`null` values from `long`s and appropriately have a `String` representation like `"P0Y0M0DT2H0M0.000S"`. Whatever makes your application server behave differently is not caused by the duration implementation. And as @dave_thompson_085 already pointed out, there’s no configuration option.